# How to read and delete messages log in call logs?

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts, mms

I can read and delete all call log and sms/mms message using below content uris.

```
ContentResolver cr;
Cursor cursor = cr.query(contentUri, null, where, null, null);  // read
cr.delete(contentUri, where, null); // delete

Calls.CONTENT_URI; // Call Log Uri.
Sms.CONTENT_URI // SMS Uri // Uri.parse("content://sms")
Mms.CONTENT_URI // MMS Uri // Uri.parse("content://mms")
```

So I can get count of logs. and delete them.

But Text message logs (in contacts app. see attached images) are not deleted. (Messages are deleted)

My test device is Samsung Galaxy S4 mini.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung custom message logs are not a standard Android `ContentProvider`: there is no standard way to access them and unless Samsung implemented a custom `ContentProvider` for them there is probably no way to access them.